# Time saved in my database is advanced of almost 15hours

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, timezone

Im using php under Laravel Framework and MySql. My problem is when i save date and time into my DB the hour that being saved is advanced of almost 15 hours.

I already configured my php ini and even my timezone into 'Asia/Manila'. BTW my code in getting current date and time goes like this

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Did you restart Apache after changing the timezone?  What is the server timezone?

Comment: Does using `NOW()` directly to your query out of the option? I'm also having that problem before, so I just used `NOW()` to my query. `INSERT INTO table (datecolumn) VALUES (NOW())`.

Comment: yah ive already restarted my apache server and i even used date_default_timezone_set code but still get the same error. When I use NOW() the date saved is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 an error again.

Comment: Since you say you're using Laravel, check the configuration http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration

Comment: @ErvinBeñez What is the data type of that column?

Comment: is there any other method to change server timezone?

Comment: datetime @LoganWayne

Comment: You have to set your column's data type to either, `DATE` or `DATETIME`. Using `NOW()` in this type of column would not typically cause an insertion of  `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Comment: could also be your code and how it's used. Are you checking for errors anywhere? Don't leave that out of the equation. Try changing your "shown" code to `$date = "2015-07-29 10:00:00";` see what that gives. If your variable isn't quoted in the query, it will fail and that the default value for the column is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Comment: someone posted an "answer". you can take it up with them and see. I've said what I could, which I'm betting on the above. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to handle this but since you mentioned Laravel, I will assume you would like to use one recommended method under this framework.

Despite Laravel wont attach you to use any specific method of handling date and time, it is suggested as a good practice to use a consistent way to handle certain type of data.

You may use a component like **Carbon** to [mutate](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) and achieve that task. There is a very good explanation with examples in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084619/how-to-update-the-timezone-for-the-timestamps-created-at-and-updated-at-manage).

Try to avoid direct handling of data that might require you to duplicate code among all your application. Also avoid tampering with PHP configuration, as the intent of the framework is to let you work in a higher level of abstraction.