# How to change the time zone in the model without touching the main time zone of the framework?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

How can be changed timezone on `created_at` field of `User` model? For example now app timezone is `UTC` and I must change timezone `created_at` field to `Europe/Paris` and updated_at field timezone to `Europe/London` before save data to database. I have sample code to change field timezone. But I don't know where use it on model. My sample code to change timezone:

```
$this->created_at->timezone('Europe/London')->format('d:H:i');
$this->updated_at->timezone('Europe/Paris')->format('H:i');
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084619/how-to-update-the-timezone-for-the-timestamps-created-at-and-updated-at-manage

Comment: Try this one; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084619/how-to-update-the-timezone-for-the-timestamps-created-at-and-updated-at-manage

Answer (score 0):

you can change Time zone in .env file for all of your application you can change your time zone like this

// .env file

```
'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC')
```

you must change UTC with your custom time zone as you wish

also you can change time zone in app.php folder

'timezone' => 'UTC'

bu if you want change just format Time , you can easily set this protected property in your Model

```
protected $dateFormat
```

for example

```
protected $dateFormat = 'U';
```

you can set your time zone in this address

https://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Thanks for answering @hamidreza nikoonia but I must change or save date on created_at field without changing general timezone of laravel framework.

Answer (score 0):

you can also create  method in your Model , ex. Local Scope like this

```
public function scopeChangeTimezone($query)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::parse($value, 'America/New_York')-> 
      timezone($this->deployment->timezone);
}
```

and remember import Carbon  and change America/New_York to your custom timezone

```
$data = App\User::->ChangeTimezone()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

you must create method with scope prefix and then use without scope prefix

if  you want get data from model or use this in any where you can do like this

check this , and call me if this way not working, then i try

Comment: Ok, I will reply you soon after testing your example code, I am little busy right now.

Answer (score 0):

Using [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):

```php
namespace App\Models;

// ...
use Carbon\Carbon;

// ....
public function getCreatedAtAttribute(){
    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['created_at'])->setTimezone("TimeZone identifier" );
}

public function getUpdatedAtAttribute(){
    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['updated_at'])->setTimezone("TimeZone identifier" );
}
```